# If he were to cancel the deal tomorrow, I would be devastated

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives, conditionals

1. If they **were to** *cancel* the deal *tomorrow*, I would be devastated.
2. If they **canceled** the deal *tomorrow*, I would be devastated.
3. If he **were to** *cancel* the deal *tomorrow*, I would be devastated.
4. If he **canceled** the deal *tomorrow*, I would be devastated.

Do (1) and (2), (3) and (4) mean the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all four mean the same thing, except that in 1 & 2 it could be one or more people canceling the deal. They all sound natural to me as a native English speaker.